# Why does `queue = queue.append(item)` in a function not change the passed queue to `None`?

Tags: python, queue

My textbook includes the following functions as an easy way to implement a queue in Python using a list:

```
def enqueue(queue, item):
     queue = queue.append(item)
     #print(queue)
def dequeue(queue):
     return queue.pop(0)
def isEmpty(queue):
     return len(queue)==0
def createQueue():
     return []
```

My questions regard the `enqueue()` function.

1) What's the purpose of `queue =`? Since `list.append()` does not return anything, why not leave it out?

2) When I added `print(queue)` (shown as the commented out last line in `enqueue()`) to `enqueue()`, it printed `None`, which makes sense, but why does `queue = queue.append(item)` not change the original queue/list passed to the function to `None` (as a list is a mutable), instead just changing the local variable `queue`?

Comment: Sample I/O? with actual and desired results?

Comment: what are you getting when you remove `queue = ` from the line `queue = queue.append(item)`, i.e., just use `queue.append(item)`, and can you check.

Comment: Your textbook is simply bad. You should never assign the result of `append`.

Comment: But why do you think it should change the variable that is passed in? That is not how assignment works in Python. The list is mutated by the `append`, though.

Comment: I think this is more of a who wrote your textbook. He smells like a java developer (see the non pythonic isEmpty instead of is_empty). That said I could imagine your teacher not knowing lists are mutable and not knowing about what you say.
queue=queue.append(item) is a BAD idea, append returns none

Comment: Problem is with scope, queue = queue.append() does NOT modify the original queue, but the one created inside the function, queue.append() modifies the original object, as the assignment does NOT overwrite the original object, but the append modifies it. lets clarify :

queue = queue.append(item)
1- Appends item to the original list queue, because lists are mutable.2-Creates a new local var called queue, and assigns the return of append to it (None).

Comment: @user5173426 I'm not saying that it does not work. It works fine, was just trying to understand why it was implemented like this. @Jeril I know it works the same with and without it but I want to know why someone would choose to add `queue = `. @Daniel Regarding why I think it should change the original queue: The parameter queue is pointing at the same object the original queue is pointing to, so does `queue = ...`  not change the object the parameter `queue` is pointing to (ie. the same one the original queue points to) to `None`?